# ReactiveSwift observers does not work when set up in initializers of NSObject subclasses

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

i hit a weird issue while working when I set up a observer in the initializer of a class, subclassing from NSObject and for whatever reason it's not getting called. I tried removing `duringLifetimeOf` operator and retaining with a disposable only to dispose in `deinit`, that dint work either.

PS: The same code works when I dont subclass from `NSObject`. Some example code below -

```
protocol ObservableFeatureSource {
    var futureFeatureChanges: Signal<AnyFeature, NoError> { get }
}

extension FeatureManager: ReactiveExtensionsProvider {}

extension Reactive where Base: FeatureManager {
    func monitorFeatureChanges<F>(for feature: ApplicationFeature<F>) -> Signal<ApplicationFeature<F>, NoError> {
        let observableSources = FeatureManager.shared.sources
            .flatMap { ($0 as? ObservableFeatureSource)?.futureFeatureChanges }
        return Signal<AnyFeature, NoError>.merge(observableSources)
            .filterMap { $0 == feature ? feature : nil }
    }
}

final class Example: NSObject {
   static let shared = Example()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        FeatureManager.shared.reactive
            .monitorFeatureChanges(for: .someFeature)
            .observe(on: UIScheduler())
            .take(duringLifetimeOf: self)
            .observeValues({ _ in
                debugPrint("print something")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your `init` is definitely being called?

Comment: @jjoelson yes, i can confirm it's called.

Comment: Try the `logEvents` operator to see if it is maybe disposed immediately...

Comment: @MeXx Thanks for the suggestion, using `logEvents` I can see it's getting disposed too soon. I was suspecting the same and hence earlier I tried explicitly retaining w/ a `Disposable` and then disposing that in `deinit`.  That did not work either, so I suspect is it something w/ the lifetime of `NSObject`. Is it different than the non-`NSObject` types?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/NSObject%2BLifetime.swift

Comment: @Manoj, the fact that it didn't work with a normal `Disposable` should mean that the issue is unrelated to `NSObject+Lifetime`, right?

Comment: Maybe try removing `.take(duringLifetimeOf: self)` again and putting a break point in `deinit` to see if the object is getting cleaned up earlier than you expect.

Comment: @jjoelson as I mentioned earlier, I had tried that too.  That's not happening either :(

Comment: Well my last idea is if `logEvents` is showing early disposal than add `on(disposed:)` and stick a break point in the block and see if the stack trace can tell you anything about what is initiating the disposal.

Comment: @Manoj you mentioned that you tried manual disposal in `deinit` but have you checked at which point `deinit` is actually called? What @jjoelson suggested was that maybe the whole `Example` instance is cleaned up much earlier than you expect

Comment: @MeXx `Example` instance is not getting cleaned up yet.

Comment: I also wanted to see how notification works, so tried w/ `NotificationCenter.default.reactive.notifications(forName:...` - which is working as expected.